# How to load the user’s last selected value for a slider when the app relaunches?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am new to Xcode and I am using Objective C in OSX.

I am trying to load the user’s last selected value for a slider when the app relaunches.

my code for the slider is…

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

    amount = [self.amountSlider integerValue];

    NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", amount];

    [self.amountLabel setStringValue:amountString];
}
```

I have this setter…

```
- (void)setInteger:(NSInteger)valueforKey:(NSString *)defaultName{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"amountString" forKey:@"amountSlider"];
}
```

I would like to know how to code the getter.

A step-by-step instructions with code will be appreciated.

Any improvements/corrections to my existing code above would also be appreciated.

Comment: Store the value in `NSUserDefaults` and assign the value to your slider when the app relaunches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make separate functions for retrieving, saving from defaults like this.

```
- (void)saveValueToUserDefaults:(NSString *)pValue key:(NSString *)kKey {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [self removeValueFromUserDefaults:kKey];

    [defaults setObject:pValue forKey:kKey];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

- (void)removeValueFromUserDefaults:(NSString *)kKey {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:kKey]) {
        [defaults removeObjectForKey:kKey];
    }
}

- (NSString *)retriveValueFromUserDefaults:(NSString *)kKey {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:kKey]) {
        return [defaults objectForKey:kKey];
    } else {
        return kStringEmpty;
    }
}
```

This will make simple to save and retrieve values from defaults.
Like-

```
[self saveValueToUserDefaults:YOUR_AMOUNT forKey:YOUR_KEY];
```

and get like this,

```
YOUR_AMOUNT = [self retriveValueFromUserDefaults:YOUR_KEY];
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked for it :D 
in your class create integer variable called `amountChecker = 0`

create a function called checker like this :

```
-(void) checker {
     if (amount == amountChecker){
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:amountLabel.text forKey:@"amountSlider"];
     }
    else
        amount = amountChecker;
}
```

then .. in this function :

```
- (IBAction)sliderChanged:(id)sender {

    amount = [self.amountSlider integerValue];

    NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", amount];

    [self.amountLabel setStringValue:amountString];
    [self performSelector:@selector(checker) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

now this code will only store your value if a second passes and your slider didn't change , instead of storing your value like 60 times every second :D 
it all starts when you change the slider then after one second it will check if the value changed if not it will store it

and when you reopen the app you will use this code :

```
amount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"amountSlider"];
```